# how to generate possible combination of 1's and 0's in matrix? using java

Tags: java, matrix

I have to generate reordered matrix representing all permutation of 1' & 0's in a matrix, how can i do it? any idea?

Comment: What exactly is a *reordered matrix* in the scope of your question? A matrix holding all permutations is trivial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shuffling a 2D array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506787/shuffling-a-2d-array-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the *reordered* constraint for a moment:

For a given number n for columns, count i from 0 to (2^(n)-1). For each i, add a row to your matrix where each cell is one digit of the binary representation of i. Then you'll have all possible combinations for a given number of binaries.

Result for n=3:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```